# Como colocar valor máximo num campo Date em Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você conseguem observar pela imagem que o campo está aceitando mais de dez digitos, o que preciso fazer é permitir que o usuário consiga somente digita dez digitos no campo data, estou tendo dificuldade de corrigir o bug por falta de experiência.

O componente html é esse abaixo;

```
 <div class="form-group col-4">
    <label>Período</label>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 0">
      <input type="date" class="form-control col-5" name="dataInicial" [(ngModel)]="filtro.dataInicial" InputDateValidationOnBlur/>
      <span class="col-2" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 5px">até</span>
      <input type="date" class="form-control col-5" name="dataFinal" [(ngModel)]="filtro.dataFinal" InputDateValidationOnBlur/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Por favor preciso muito de ajuda, eu encontrei esse link abaixo, não sei isso ajuda a clarear para poderem me ajudar.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-triyfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: já tentou colocar `maxlength=10`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input  ou ainda no jeito angular: `ng-maxlength="10"`?

Comment: eu já tentei, o maxlength não suporta campo tipo date.

Comment: Preciso mesmo tentar validar o número de digitos com tipo date.

Comment: Eae, blz?
O campo Date já tem o format, min e max não estou entendo a necessidade de validar o length sendo que a mascara do input já cuida disso.

Answer (score 1):

Então, parece ser um bug no **Html** este problema com inputs do tipo `date`, fiz um exemplo abaixo que pode lhe ajudar aí no caso, basicamente pego o valor do input e quando o valor for o determinado eu pulo para o próximo input de data, pode ver o  funcionamento em um exemplo [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-date):

**TS:**

```
@ViewChild('dataInicial') dataInicial: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('dataFinal') dataFinal: ElementRef;

Valor() {
  let valor = this.dataInicial.nativeElement.value;
  if(valor[0] == 1) this.dataFinal.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group col-4">
  <label>Período</label>
  <div class="row" style="margin: 0">
    <input type="date" class="form-control col-5" name="dataInicial" #dataInicial (input)="Valor()">
    <span class="col-2" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">até</span>
    <input type="date" class="form-control col-5" name="dataFinal" #dataFinal>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou utilizar os atributos **`max`** e **`min`** para limitar uma data, aí neste caso o próprio **HTML** se encarrega de validar a entrada. Exemplo, se digitar no input um valor maior que o máximo **`(31/12/2100)`** ou menor que o mínimo **`(01/01/1900)`**, ao se passar o mouse sobre o input pode ser visto uma mensagem de erro, e se ao tentar clicar com as setas do input, o próprio Html se encarrega de inserir datas válidas, *"no Firefox esses atributos min e max, não surtem efeito"*:

```html
<input type="date" id="festa" name="festa" min="1900-01-01" max="2100-12-31">
```